# Nested where with wherePivot fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Laravel Eloquent function;

```
Category::select('id')->where('parent_category_id', null)
            ->with('children')
            ->with(['children.consultants' => function ($query) use($consultantId) {
                $query->where('users.id', $consultantId)
                    ->with(['categories' => function($query) {
                        $query->wherePivot('status', CategoryRequestStatus::Accepted)->orWherePivot('status', CategoryRequestStatus::Requested);
                    }]);
            }])->get();
```

And it's executed query;

```
select `categories`.*, `categories_consultants`.`consultant_id` as `pivot_consultant_id`, `categories_consultants`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `categories_consultants`.`status` as `pivot_status`, `categories_consultants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `categories_consultants`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `categories` inner join `categories_consultants` on `categories`.`id` = `categories_consultants`.`category_id` where `categories_consultants`.`consultant_id` in (4) and `categories_consultants`.`status` = 1 or `categories_consultants`.`status` = 0
```

I want to make this query's last `or` to be in parentheses

```
select `categories`.*, `categories_consultants`.`consultant_id` as `pivot_consultant_id`, `categories_consultants`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `categories_consultants`.`status` as `pivot_status`, `categories_consultants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `categories_consultants`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `categories` inner join `categories_consultants` on `categories`.`id` = `categories_consultants`.`category_id` where `categories_consultants`.`consultant_id` in (4) and (`categories_consultants`.`status` = 1 or `categories_consultants`.`status` = 0)
```

I've changed it like below to solve this but It gives an error `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWherePivot()`

```
Category::select('id')->where('parent_category_id', null)
            ->with('children')
            ->with(['children.consultants' => function ($query) use($consultantId) {
                $query->where('users.id', $consultantId)
                    ->with(['categories' => function($query) {
                        $query->where(function($query) {
                            $query->wherePivot('status', CategoryRequestStatus::Accepted)->orWherePivot('status', CategoryRequestStatus::Requested);
                        });
                    }]);
            }])->get();
```

Comment: Query builder should improve code readability, not decrease it. Are you sure, it will not be clearer if you write it using whereRAW for example? Or just use plain SQL?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Probably it'll be clearer if I write plain sql. But isn't it the Laravel way?

Comment: Well... I don't know what is "Laravel way". If this is the law, that says: "Use Laravel features everywhere even if leads to mess and debugging nightmare" - screw that way. Care about database compatibility (query builder helps here), about code cleanness (query builder sometimes helps too), about extendibility (you can give your query builder to plugin as an extension point). But don't care about some "way", that stops you from writing clean, good, nice code.